# Increase space between largest bar and top grid line in charts.js

Tags: chart.js

I am trying to add more space between the top of the highest bar and the top grid line. Data wise everything is fine - the number is smaller than the top grid line.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Inside the chart `options`, You could define a value for [`scales.yAxis.ticks.max`](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/radial/linear.html#tick-options) as follows:

```js
var myBarChart = new Chart(document.getElementById("myChart"), {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "G", "H"],
    datasets: [{
      backgroundColor: "lightblue",
      data: [3200, 3250, 3300, 3350, 3400, 3450, 3500],
    }]
  },
  options: {
    legend: {
      display: false
    },
    tooltips: {
      enabled: false
    },
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          min: 3000,
          max: 3600,
          stepSize: 200
        }
      }]
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart" height="60"></canvas>
```

**UPDATE**

In case the data is dynamic, `yAxis` maximum value needs to be computed from the values. In that case however, I would rather define `scales.yAxis.ticks.suggestedMax`.

```js
const labels = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "G", "H"];
const data = [3200, 3250, 3300, 3350, 3400, 3450, 3500];

var myBarChart = new Chart(document.getElementById("myChart"), {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: labels,
    datasets: [{
      backgroundColor: "lightblue",
      data: data,
    }]
  },
  options: {
    legend: {
      display: false
    },
    tooltips: {
      enabled: false
    },
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          suggestedMin: Math.min.apply(null, data) * 0.95,
          suggestedMax: Math.max.apply(null, data) * 1.05
        }
      }]
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart" height="60"></canvas>
```

Comment: In that case you need to compute the option. I updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: This is not working now. Probably because of the version change. The following is from the official doc of the chartjs
```let chart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
        datasets: [{
            label: 'First dataset',
            data: [0, 20, 40, 50]
        }],
        labels: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April']
    },
    options: {
        scales: {
            y: {
                suggestedMin: 50,
                suggestedMax: 100
            }
        }
    }
});```